# end to end test failing in IE but passes in Chrome

Tags: angularjs

I am using the end to end test specified in the Github [intro to Karma](https://github.com/ksunair/introtokarma). I was able to run runner.html in Chrome pointing to my localhost '/test/runner.html' and all the test ran successfully. But when I run the same tests in IE10 and all tests failed with following errors

> 65ms
>
> browser navigate to '../../app/index.html'TypeError: Object doesn't
>   support property or method 'resumeBootstrap'    at Anonymous function
>   (/test/lib/angular-scenario.js:26240:11)    at
>   dispatch (/test/lib/angular-scenario.js:3063:6)
>   at eventHandle
>   (/test/lib/angular-scenario.js:2681:5)

Is it because of limitation of IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help, workaround for the same is also specified in it, and you can more dig into the same too if you want.
[1.1.4 scenario runner does not work in IE (8 -> 10)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2370)